# Python Postgres Insert Error: TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting

Tags: python-3.x, typeerror

I'm receiving the following error code when trying to insert the below results from the below code, into a text field in a Postgres database:

TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting

> [
>       {
>           "id": 271,
>           "legacy_id": 43,
>           "country_id": 320,
>           "logo_path": "https://cdn.sportmonks.com/images/soccer/leagues/271.png",
>           "name": "Superliga",
>           "is_cup": false,
>           "current_season_id": 12919,
>           "current_round_id": 167381,
>           "current_stage_id": 7088927,
>           "live_standings": true,
>           "coverage": {
>               "topscorer_goals": true,
>               "topscorer_assists": true,
>               "topscorer_cards": true
>           }
>       },
>       {
>           "id": 501,
>           "legacy_id": 66,
>           "country_id": 1161,
>           "logo_path": "https://cdn.sportmonks.com/images/soccer/leagues/501.png",
>           "name": "Premiership",
>           "is_cup": false,
>           "current_season_id": 12963,
>           "current_round_id": null,
>           "current_stage_id": null,
>           "live_standings": true,
>           "coverage": {
>               "topscorer_goals": true,
>               "topscorer_assists": true,
>               "topscorer_cards": true
>           }
>       } ]

I've tried replacing and editing the dictionary to remove ' and "

```
data1 = json.load(response)

volume = (len(data1['data']))


data = (data1["data"])

jsonstr = (json.dumps(data, indent=4))

print(jsonstr)

connection = psycopg2.connect("host=localhost dbname=xxx user=xxx password=xxx")

cur = connection.cursor()

connection.autocommit = True

query =  "INSERT INTO xxx.xxx (xxx) VALUES (%s);"
sql = "INSERT INTO xxx.xxx VALUES (%s)"
cur.execute(sql, jsonstr)
```

I can't find out what is wrong - probably something simple :)

Answer (score 0):

Finally found out the solution... you have to pass a tuple into cur.execute so:

`cur.execute(sql, (jsonstr,))` works